# How to find a number after a character in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I find a numeric value after a character in the same cell.

For example: Find number `01` after `J*`. I have a few rows and in each row are value like `J*01` or `J*08`.

Currently I'm trying to separate characters and numbers using VBA `InStr` function:

```
 Sub zz()
   Dim ii As Long, z As Integer, xlastrow As Long
   Dim yy As String
   xlastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
     For ii = 1 To xlastrow
       yy = "J*"
       z = 1         
       If IsNumeric(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & ii)) Then       
         'This line is separating numbers after J* character and pasting to sheet2
         Seprate.Find.Range("B" & ii, yy).Value = Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("A" & z)
       End If
       z = z + 1
     Next ii    
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another User Defined Function that will return all of the digits after a particular string (prefix).  In the arguments, you specify the string to be processed, and the prefix to be used.  You can also specify if the prefix should be case-sensitive.  The default is for it to NOT be case sensitive, but that is easily changed.

The UDF uses regular expressions to do the text-processing.  First we remove everything up to and including the prefix.  Then we remove all of the non-digits in the remainder.

===================================

```
Option Explicit
Function DigitsAfter(sInput, sPrefix, Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim re As Object
    Dim S As String
    Dim sPatPrefix As String
    Const sPat As String = "\D"

'Intialize Regex engine
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = Not MatchCase
End With

'Generate the digit prefix
re.Pattern = "(.)"
sPatPrefix = ".*" & re.Replace(sPrefix, "\$1")

'Remove characters up to and including the prefix
re.Pattern = sPatPrefix
    If re.test(sInput) = False Then

'Exit if prefix not in string
        DigitsAfter = "Digit Prefix not in String"
        Exit Function

'now remove all the non-digits that are left
    Else
        S = re.Replace(sInput, "")
        re.Pattern = sPat
        DigitsAfter = re.Replace(S, "")
    End If
End Function
```

=====================================

Here is a short routine showing how it might be used within a larger macro:

======================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestDigitFunction()
    Const S As String = "abc12x97J*24AAA123"

    MsgBox S & vbLf & DigitsAfter(S, "J*")

End Sub
```

======================================

Answer (score 0):

This addresses your *question* rather than your sample code.  If you have a string like:

**q1w2e3r4asJ*66bvft654**

and want to extract the two digits following J* then try this little *UDF*

```
Public Function RetDigits(sIN As String) As String
    Dim lookFor As String, v As String
    lookFor = "J*"
    RetDigits = ""
    If InStr(sIN, lookFor) = 0 Then Exit Function
    ary = Split(sIN, lookFor)
    If Len(ary(1)) < 2 Then Exit Function
    RetDigits = Left(ary(1), 2)
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a version that will return more than **2** digits:

```
Public Function RetDigits(sIN As String) As String
    Dim lookFor As String, v As String, ary
    Dim i As Long, CH As String
    lookFor = "J*"
    RetDigits = ""
    If InStr(sIN, lookFor) = 0 Then Exit Function
    ary = Split(sIN, lookFor)
    If Len(ary(1)) < 2 Then Exit Function

    For i = 1 To Len(ary(1))
        CH = Mid(ary(1), i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            RetDigits = RetDigits & CH
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

and here is a test routine:

```
Sub main()
    Dim st As String, out As String
    st = "hfskfhjsdfshjJ*123456"
    out = RetDigits(st)
    MsgBox out
End Sub
```

Comment: Every time when i call it inside my sub its not running it, keep on getting Doesn't support method error also i want all the number after J* for ex if i have input q1ww343dJ*333F44 .... i want my output to be 33344 so after J* get 333 and ignore F then 44 thanks

Comment: @user3795861  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: ya i checked it but 
st = "hdfdfdsJ*12345" instead
st should be range cause i am looking for J* inside column C 
st = worksheets("sheet1").Range("C") and still getting error

Comment: what is st = "hfskfhjsdfshjJ*123456" ... what does it represent.

Comment: It is **sample data** to see if the function works.

Comment: how come when i change it to st = worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i) it doesn't work, I have to loop through Range C to find J*

Comment: Just use a cell.............in **D1** enter **=RetDigits(C1)** and copy down the column.

Comment: @user3795861 It doesn't work that way because you're trying to pass a range and you need to pass a string. Add `.Value` to the end. For instance: `st = RetDigits(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value)` will run return all the numeric digits in cell `Ci` that comes after `J*`.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent It doesn't work either way or when i set it up to st = retdigit........... still returning value = 0 so i  guess when you set up RetDigits = "" thats why its returning as empty cell

Answer (score 0):

To find the value of exactly two digits after "`J*`", you don't need VBA. If the string is in A1, just use: `=VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH("J*";A1)+2;2))`. The `SEARCH` function searches for "`J*`". `MID` takes the next two characters and `VALUE` converts those to a value.

Comment: I have to use vba, im comparing couple sheets together + some other stuff so i can't do anything without vba